# Upgrade iTextsharp 5.5.4 to 5.5.7 in c#

Tags: c#, itext

i am using itextsharp 5.5.4 in c# application and due to some complications in pdf, i want to upgrade to 5.5.7.

My question is, can i replace the existing version with new one or i need to rebuild the application with latest dll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just trying it? C# cares about parameter signature, so that starting will fail in case the API has an incompatible change. Normally such minor version differences should not be a problem

Comment: If you don't have it set in your proj file as "use specific version" and there are no version-breaking changes or you do not refer to these changed pieces, you should be alright...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you used NuGet or referenced the DLL directly, you should be able to do an in-place upgrade unless the API has changed significantly. I would recommend NuGet for managing dependencies and upgrades but if you have a direct reference you can just update the reference to the new version.

Comment: i have direct ref to that dll and when i updated it with new version i got error as Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 1):

I would say - it depends.

You cannot know whether library is compatible backwards. Some metadata can be embedded into your DLL which will change with new version.

What is more, you can have specific version bindings, what can break your app with the new iTextSharp version.

If library is installed in GAC, that would require new version installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace it directly (maybe you can, see below), you'll have to recompile your application. The API is the same, you won't have problems there.

Another option is using `<assemblyBinding>` in a config file to trick the app into accepting an assembly with a different version. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.